# Check if node already attached to AVAudioEngine

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode

I successfully attach AVAudioPlayer nodes to my AVAudioEngine. However, I need to later check if these nodes have already been attached to it (so I don't re-add them).

Is there any certain property on the engine that I can check to see if its already been attached?

Answer (score 1):

You could check the engine property of the AVAudioPlayerNode and if nil this means it is not attached to an audio engine.

```
for playerNode in yourPlayerNodeArray {
        if playerNode.engine == nil {
            yourEngine.attach(playerNode)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks for me like a solution. Let me know if there are any pitfalls?

Answer (score 0):

The implementation more than likely uses an interface implementation and has an API associated with it. I would suggest reading the API to check if a function exists that returns a list of (active) nodes attached.

Comment: Yes I read the docs but didn't see anything helpful so am wondering if there are any other ways anybody knows

Comment: Create a **model** and store the a reference to the attached nodes. And create a static API for the **model** so that you can store and retrieve a reference to the nodes.